# Minimize billing address if completed in checkout for WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to ****minimize** the billing address** from checkout if the user has already filled up the billing form (from a previous order or if the user has done it previously from the "my account" page).

I have tried this method to hide the billing address completely but it doesn't work at all

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() && !has_billing()){
        unset($fields['billing']);
        $fields['billing'] = array();
    }
    return $fields;
}

// Check the meta of Postcode and Country if they are entered.
function has_billing($user_id = false){
            if(!$user_id)
                $user_id = get_current_user_id();

            $shipping_postcode = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_postcode', true );
            $shipping_country = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_country', true );

            // Fetch more meta for the condition has needed.  
            if($shipping_postcode && $shipping_country){
                return true;
            }

            return false;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't `!has_billing()` have to be `has_billing()`?

Answer (score 1):

You are unsetting the form fields that are being submitted. If you hide them in CSS that should work or you will need to populate the forms dynamically when you click the checkout button.

Comment: Can you please tell me more! I didn't understand

Comment: Remove what you have done above using filters to the remove billing fields, and hide them via CSS. Then try checking out - this should work as the fields are present